# PropertyInfo.CanWrite Property true in debug build, false in release build

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

We are building an android application using Xamarin's mono for android and for a cross platform persistence solution we are using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

In a debug build everything is OK, all use cases pass and we're happy. When building for release the data layer is not functional at all. Since it's in release mode it's pretty difficult to debug (by definition I guess) but eventually I zoomed in on the problem:
When creating the table the sqlite-net framework iterates over the properties and uses only those which are writable. The problem is that in release mode all the properties of out POCO return false for PropertyInfo.CanWrite.

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you can reproduce this and suspect a bug, asking in the #mono IRC channel on irc.gnome.org might be more appropriate.

Comment: My question is: what makes the property read only in release builds? The POCO's property has a setter so the CanWrite should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the way you link the project.
For full details, see [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/276/reflection-on-type-in-dll-allways-returns-propertyinfo-canwritefalse).